# How to search for iBeacons when using view controllers

Tags: ios, swift3, ibeacon

I am a new iOS developer so please bear with me if I seem a little ignorant.

I am trying to make an app for a gallery. I want to use iBeacons in each category of the gallery. I know how to make this all happen if I am only using one view controller. I can make it range for the beacon and once in a certain range send a pop up stating "You have entered the "XXXX" area. Would you like to view these exhibits?"

If the user presses yes, it will take them to it. However, the problem I am running into is that I need to have quite a few view controllers. So How can I get the ranging to happen in the background of all of them? Should I create a separate Swift file and do all the ranging there and then call that class in each view? Or should (or even could) I do all the beacon code in the app delegate.

The next problem that I have is how to segue to the "category" view controller when a user is in a view controller that doesn't have the actual segue? Say VC 1 has a segue to VC 2 with identifier #3. Can I call the segue with ID #3 from VC 5, for an example? Or is it better to instantiate the views?

Will appreciate any tips.

Comment: Not a good idea to ask a very broad how-to question, particularly followed by another question that is completely orthogonal to the subject line. Those are separate questions, and you should really use the site search function to try to find answers before you post questions. I'm sure the segue question has been more than adequately covered in other questions and answers here. As far as the design help - usually it is expected that someone has a grasp of the technology, looked at tutorials and usually have provided code to look at, otherwise the questions tend to get closed as being too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of centralized logic fits well into the `AppDelegate` as it is designed to handle global app logic.  It is easy and a common practice to set up beacon monitoring and ranging in the `didFinishLaunching` callback.

To launch specific view controllers, it is easiest to instantiate and present them programmatically (rather than using a segue) when a change is needed based on beacon detection in a callback in the `AppDelegate`.

Comment: Ok.Thanks for the help. I will set it up in the app delegate.

Comment: I see that you are from Radius Networks. Those are the beacons that I am using. They work great.